# Speed of data retrieval via data frame column name vs column index vs matrix indices

Tags: r, matrix, dataframe

I wish to run a loop to retrieve entries from a data frame/matrix. I am interested to know which method will give me the fastest data retrieval. E.g.

```
height = c(100,125,188)
length = c(34,25,99)
body_dim = data.frame(height,length)
body_dim_mat = as.matrix(body_dim)
```

Which is the fastest?

Option 1:

```
x = body_dim[2,"length"]
```

Option 2:

```
x = body_dim[2,2]
```

Option 3:

```
x = body_dim_mat[2,2]
```

Comment: I'm going to guess 3 assuming you don't count the time to convert to matrix.  Even faster would be `body_dim_mat[5]` which should be equivalent.  That said, you can download `microbenchmark` package and find out for yourself.

Comment: It's a data frame because I am using read.csv, not sure how long it will take to do as.matrix. I am interested in the reasoning behind it as well. Obviously it is less time consuming for me to just reference column names.

Comment: generally the direct indices will be fastest as there is no needed mapping b/w name and location in the vector.  A matrix also uses the primitive `[` operator, which will be faster than the `[.data.frame` operator, but again, you should test to confirm.  Easy enough to do.

Comment: I am wondering if there might be much faster approaches (to your general application) than pulling elements one at a time?

Comment: There possibly is a better way. I am compressing multirow data about one object into one row per object. A simplistic example would be multiple measurements made on fruit -> col1 is fruit, col2 are things like fruit_length, fruit_weight, col3 give the values for the respective attribute in col2.

Comment: So the new data frame would have things like fruit_type, fruit_length, fruit_weight as the columns. It would be appreciated if you could suggest a similar answered question on stackoverflow.

Comment: PLease stop using comments to amend your questions. You should edit the body of the question.

Comment: I am not using comments to amend my question. What Ricardo Saporta suggested is a totally different question.

Comment: I used microbenchmark, thanks BrodieG. It appears the last option is 20 times faster in my example. Surprisingly the second option is slower than the first. Can't post the results as I this question has not been open for more than 8 hours.

Comment: interesting, calling `body_dim_mat[2,"length"]` is only fractionally slower than option 3.